# Как в OpenGL отображаются модели?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

1. **obj** файл содержит координаты вершин, вот например одна из них: 
   `v -1.174286 32.706123 6.473185` как это представить в вид от `-1` до `1` как это требует **opengl**? Есть ли функция перевода? (Для работы с геометрическими преобразованием использую библиотеку **joml**)
2. у меня **obj** не содержит нормалей, как задать вектор направление? Что в этом случае нужно делать?

Comment: там оказывается opengl сам все переводит:) прикольно

Comment: Может вам проще взять `umodel` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В OpenGL используется иерархия преобразований для вывода на экран. Для этого используются матрицы трансформации модели (например перемещение, вращение, масштабирование и т.п.), вида (преобразование из мировых координат в координаты которые видит камера), проекции (преобразование из координат камеры в `-1..1` координаты, например ортографическая или перспективная).
   Т.о. вы можете задать ортографическую проекцию произвольного размера (например `-100..412`), в которой иметь модель так же произвольного размера (например `10..120`) и получить ее на экране.
   С точки зрения работы с готовым движком - вы просто задаете свойства виртуальной "камеры" (положение, ориентацию, зум) и размещаете объект в сцене (положение, ориентацию, размер). Ни про какие `-1..1` вам знать не надо.
2. Нормали достаточно просто рассчитываются по полигонам/треугольникам. Нормаль - это перпендикуляр к поверхности. Посчитав кросс-продукт между двумя векторами в треугольнике мы получим его нормаль. (направление которой зависит от направления векторов).

   ```
   function VectorCrossProduct(const A, B: TKMVertex3): TKMVertex3;
   begin
     Result.X := A.Y * B.Z - A.Z * B.Y;
     Result.Y := A.Z * B.X - A.X * B.Z;
     Result.Z := A.X * B.Y - A.Y * B.X;
   end;
   ```

   Далее вам нужны будут нормали всех вершин. Их можно получить, например, взяв среднее между всеми нормалями полигонов которые используют данную вершину.

Comment: а впринципе есть команда normalize:)

Comment: Normalize только нормализует нормали (делает их единичной длины).

Comment: 2. а как можно найти нормаль, зная только координаты треугольника? забыл, к сожалению, аналитическую геометрию

Comment: @МаксимСавельев Допустим у вас треугольник есть `АВС`, из его точек вы можете получить 2 вектора - `АВ` и `АС`. Посчитав кросс-продукт между ними, вы получите нормаль (которую надо нормализовать - сделать единичной длины). Если нормаль смотрит "не в ту сторону", просто разверните один из векторов, например считайте для `АВ` и `СА`.